# Sybase: Convert Binary to String in query

Tags: php, sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I am trying to retrieve a value from a sybase SQL anywhere database using PHP. The problem is, that the value ist only available in binary.
When I try to SELECT the value and print it, php interprets only garbage like this:

```
I7?J?`X
```

but the string I want should look like this:

```
0x2619fa68af56664271075bb3e74620e4 (value changed for security).
```

I already tried several convert()'s and other stuff, but it's always only garbage or misinterpreted.

I only tried it directly in the query, because that felt more natively. if there is a better way using PHP I would be ok with it.

[image]